# Laravel Passport's Password Grant Flow for First-party Apps

Tags: php, laravel, security, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I'm using [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport) to give access to some parts of my API to third-party apps.

But, I also use my own API through my own first-party Native Android App.
So, I looked over the whole internet for the best practice in this case, but getting stuck to get to a conclusion.

Here are the possibilities I found:

## Possibility #01

I can follow the [**User Credential Password Grant Flow**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#password-grant-tokens).
In this case I need to pass a `client_secret` and `client_id` to the authorization server. In order to keep them safe I can't write them in my mobile application's source code (APKs are decompilable...).

So, I have 2 choices.

#### Possibility #01 - Choice A

Proxyfying through my own server and inject the secret before calling the oauth endpoint:

```php
$proxy = Request::create('/oauth/token', 'post', [
    'grant_type' => 'password',
    'client_id' => 1,
    'client_secret' => 'myownclientsecretishere',
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password
]);
$proxy->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
$response = app()->handle($proxy);
```

#### Possibility #01 - Choice B

Inject the secret when calling the oauth endpoint using a Middleware:

```php
class InjectPasswordGrantSecret
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->request->add([
            'client_id' => 1,
            'client_secret' => 'myownclientsecretishere'
        ]);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

These are working examples, but they are also greedy in resources..
I tried to use **Apache benchmark** on my local machine and I got something like 9 requests/second.

## Possibility #02

I can follow the [**Personal Access Grant**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#personal-access-tokens).
This one doesn't look like a standard in [OAuth2](https://oauth.net/2/), it allows us to create a token through any custom route, just like this:

```php
if (! auth()->attempt(compact('username', 'password'))) {
    return error_response(__('auth.failed'));
}
$user = auth()->user();
$token = $user->createToken(null)->accessToken;
```

Using **Apache benchmark** I get better result (something like 30 requests/second).

But, token lifetime is not configurable by default and is set to 1 year (note that there are workarounds to get this lifetime configurable using a Custom Provider).

I am really wondering if this solution is meant to be used in a production environment.

Initially, I used [JWT tymon](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) library because I only had my own app. But now that I need to get it to work with first-party AND third-party apps, I thought that OAuth2 (through Laravel Passport) would be a good solution...

I hope someone can help me out with this, and explain what could be a good solution to get it to work securely and [not slowly] on production servers.

Comment: Have you tried https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#token-lifetimes? I think it applies on personal and password grant tokens.

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/162#issuecomment-319157793

Comment: @AliFarhoudi Like I said (your link confirm this). Personal Access Grant lifetime is configurable using a Custom Provider (workaround). It's the reason why I'm not sure I should use this for my own Android App in production.

Comment: There's nothing to be worried about a custom provider. When framework hasn't consider that, you can implement that in your custom way.

Comment: Looking at the links in your question, I believe you are using Laravel 5.7?

Comment: Yes at this time exactly

Comment: @Marc In that case I'd say upgrade to 6 if possible, so you can just use `Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn` in `AuthServiceProvider`.

Comment: why not use client credentials for 3rd party machine to machine applications?

Comment: The `Possibility #01 B` is really the best IMO, I don't think the performance should be worse than `Possibility #02` after all there is no proxy and both create a token in the same manner, in which case it just means there is some overhead from laravel's oauth api

Answer (score 2):

Here is the page that I always refer: https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/authorization-server/which-grant/
[image]

It says

> We strongly recommend that you use the Authorization Code flow over
> the Password grant for several reasons.
> We eliminate the password grant option.

Then, it says clearly in the diagram that you should use

> Authorization Code Grant with PKCE

and also indicates that

> If the client is a web application that has runs entirely on the front
> end (e.g. a single page web application) or a native application such
> as a mobile app you should implement the authorization code grant with
> the PKCE extension.
> You can read further in the document.

Additionally, there is a good tutorial here explaining every detail of the flow with an example:
https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/mobile-api

I hope these help.

PS: When the time I needed to authorize my users in my first party application, I had used password grant by referencing this very chart. However, it seems like it changed and password grant is now not a best practice anymore and is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done before is implemented my own controller that extends the `Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController`. Not only can you set this controller up to handle creating the tokens, you can add in routes for refreshing and revoking the tokens, as well.

For example, I had a `create` method for showing the login form, a `store` method for creating the access token, a `refresh` method for using the refresh token to refresh expired access tokens, and a `revoke` method for revoking the provided access token and related refresh token.

I can't provide exact code since the project is not open source, but this is a quick example controller with just the `store` method:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController;

class MyAccessTokenController extends AccessTokenController
{
    public function store(Request $request, ServerRequestInterface $tokenRequest)
    {
        // update the request to force your grant type, id, secret, and scopes
        $request->request->add([
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => 'your-client-id',
            'client_secret' => 'your-client-secret',
            'scope' => 'your-desired-scopes',
        ]);

        // generate the token
        $token = $this->issueToken($tokenRequest->withParsedBody($request->request->all()));

        // make sure it was successful
        if ($token->status() != 200) {
            // handle error
        }

        // return the token
        return $token;
    }
}
```

The `refresh` method would basically be the same, but the `grant_type` would be `refresh_token`.

The `revoke` method would get the authed user's token (`$token = $request->user()->token()`, revoke it (`$token->revoke()`), and then manually go through the `oauth_refresh_tokens` table for the related tokens (`access_token_id` = `$token->id`) and update the `revoked` field to `true`.

Create some routes to use your custom controller and you're good to go (NB: the `revoke` route will need the `auth:api` middleware).

Comment: So, if I understand, in your solution you add data to your request (secrets, grant_type..) in order to issue tokens (using issueToken method that comes from AccessTokenController), avoiding then an extra http request ? [compared to my solution 1a]

Comment: Can you explain what makes this better than simply using Personal Access Grant or than another solution ?